# Codeigniter3.0.1: Getting values from select and input

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a "**select**" option of category from where user select different options and if users selects "**other**" an input field is appeared ( so that user can add another category ) and post an article under that category.
I'm taking values of select and checking if input is not empty then update the same variable where i had the value for **select**.
 
Now problem is i can't seem to switch between the "**select options and input**" field, if i go with simply selecting values from select option it works fine but when user selects "other" and gave a new category to input field the variable stays with the value of select.
The following error appears when we try to add through input field:

> Error Number: 1452
>     Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails   (`ci`.`user_articles`, CONSTRAINT `article_catagory_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id_fk`) REFERENCES `catagory` (`cat_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
>    INSERT INTO user_articles (`cat_id_fk`, `title`, `article`) VALUES ( 'others', 'New title', 'My article is a marshmallow');

Here is the piece of code doing it. This is my **add_article()** function in **Model_article.php** file:

```
public function add_article()
{
        $id = $this->input->post('hiddenValue');
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $catagory_id = $this->input->post('catagory_select');

        $cat = $this->input->post('cat');

        if (!isset($cat))
        {

            $cat_input = $this->input->post('cat');

            $add_catagory = "INSERT INTO catagory (`user_id_fk`,`cat_name`) VALUES ( '{$id}' ,'{$cat_input}' ) ";
            $result_catagory = $this->db->query($add_catagory);

            $retrive_catagory = "SELECT cat_id FROM catagory WHERE cat_name = '{$cat_input}' ";

            $result = $this->db->query($retrive_catagory)->row();

            $catagory_id = $result->cat_id; 

        }

        $articletext = $this->input->post('articletext',true);

        // echo $catagory_id; 
        // die();
        $sql = " INSERT INTO user_articles (`cat_id_fk`, `title`, `article`) VALUES ( '$catagory_id', '{$title}', '{$articletext}'); ";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $this->db->affected_rows();

        if ($row) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Couldn't perform query";
            die(mysqli_error($sql));
            return false;
        }
}
```

And this is my **view_addarticle.php** file:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <?php
            // Display Result Using Ajax
            echo "<div id='result' style='display: none'>";

            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Well done! You successfully read this important alert message....</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <?php       
            echo validation_errors(); 
            echo form_open('article/submit_article'); #'add_post/submit_post'
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenValue" id="hiddenValue" value="<?php echo $session_data['id']; ?>">
            <label for="sel1">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of Article">
            <br>
            <!-- <label for="sel1">Select Catagory:</label> -->

          <script type="text/javascript">
                 function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
            {
                 console.log(nameSelect);
                if(nameSelect){
                    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
                    if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
                        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
                }}
        </script> 


               <select name="catagory_select" class="selectpicker form-control" style=" width: 150px;" onchange='admSelectCheck(this);'> 
                <option>Select Catagory</option>  
                <?php
                    foreach ($query->result() as $key):
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key->cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $key->cat_name; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <option id="admOption">others</option>
              </select>

              <br>
              <div id="admDivCheck" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Catagory Name" class="form-control"  name="cat" id="color" style='width: 170px;'/>
                </div>
             <br>
            <label for="sel1">Article:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="articletext" id="" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary "  value="Submit Article" id="submit" type="submit" style="float:right;" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller function **submit_article()** in **Article.php** file:

```
public function submit_article()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('articletext', 'Article Text', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {

        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('view_addarticle');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');

        $result = $this->model_article->add_article();

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo "Coulnd't register, contact site admin help@xyz.com";
        }

        else
        {
            // echo json_encode($result);
            redirect('account');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start I typically do all my validations in the controller, bundle them into an array and send them to the model that way...

Your error is boiling down to an SQL error... You have a Foreign Key on the 'ci.user_articles' table. Does the foreign key exist in catagory (cat_id) table(col)? You are trying to insert a value of "others" needs to be available as a key to be used? (based on the error you are showing). Typically ID's are numbers not words?

Foreign key means it needs to be in the table/col you are referencing or it will fail to insert, its what a foreign key is for... (just FYI, not assuming you don't know this, benefit to others googling later if they don't.)

Regarding the checking the field has a value or not, I would suggest using a check like:

```
if(isset($this->input->post('hiddenValue')){
    $id = $this->input->post('hiddenValue')
    }
```

Doing this means the data wont be posted if the user never actually entered anything.

If you were using the Query Helper/Query Builder you would be able to build most of the SQL using CI instead of building the queries manually, you can also just parcel everything up into an array in the controller (where I do it anyway) and just pass the array through to the model.

Using the db builder helper also means your code is portable, just food for thought on that one...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i solved my question by changing the logic exactly as you said in the start "doing bunch of validations in the controller" and y table was all set with little ambiguous way of retrieving the data from form. What i did was check the form if i have value in the input field, if not i run a separate function where input has no role. And if i caught input i'll run a function specific for that input value and i worked fine for now.

Comment: Glad the answer helped, you wouldn't need 2 completely separate functions if sending the data to the model in an array and using the CI Query Builder, look into it, once you get the hang of it, saves heaps of time...